# How to native query WHERE IN by using a Many to Many field?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

#### EXPECTED

Single native query to obtain all the pets of a certain caretaker by using the `Many to Many` field.

I'm aware that I could simply obtain the pet list from the caretaker entity, the thing is I'm going to apply other filters as well by using the `AND` keyword, so I need to have the `WHERE IN` working to begin with.

#### BRIEF SAMPLE

```
public class Caretaker {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "caretaker_pet",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "caretaker_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id"))
    private List<Pet> pets;
}

public class Pet {

    @ManyToMany // skipped for clarity
    private List<Caretaker> caretakers;
}
```

#### PROBLEM

The following native query is throwing:

`java.sql.SQLException: unknown escape sequence {non-qualified-property-ref}`
`org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement`

```
public List<Pet> getPetsBy(Caretaker caretaker) {
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "FROM Pet WHERE :caretaker IN (caretakers)")
                    .setParameter("caretaker", caretaker);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `member of` keyword to express it:

```java
public List<Pet> getPetsBy(Caretaker caretaker) {
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE :caretaker member of p.caretakers")
                    .setParameter("caretaker", caretaker);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `JPQL` query like this

```
select distinct p 
from Pet p join fetch p.caretakers caretaker
where caretaker=:caretaker
```

It returns `pet` with fetched `caretakers`. If you don't need to load `caretakers` - `member of` can be used (see another answer)